# Decimal separator in long (Java/Spring)

Tags: java, spring-boot, numberformatter

I need to put the decimal separator point in a Long, I have tried in several ways, but I need it to be dynamic since the decimal separator can change, I have tried with `DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");` but this is not dynamic and it doesn't work the way I wanted it to

Example 1

`long amount = 123456;`

`int decimal = 2;`

The result should be **`Double newAmount = 1234.56`**

Example 2

`long amount = 123456;`

`int decimal = 4;`

The result should be **`Double newAmount = 12.3456`**

Comment: "The result should be" — the result of doing _**what**_ should be 1234.56? `Long` and `long`, like `Integer` and `int` hold only integral values; they don't use decimal places, so what are you doing to the "Long amount" and the "decimal = 2" to try to get your result?

Comment: Long values are whole numbers. Where would the decimal point go?

Comment: you just have to divide / 10^decimal places for it. No formatting involved. And make that long a double or declare the dividend as double, or you lose the decimal part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
Long amount = 123456;
int decimal = 2;
double newAmount = amount.doubleValue();
newAmount = newAmount / Math.pow(10, decimal);
```

Use the pow method of [java.lang.math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) to calculate the power of a number.

Be careful to declare your variable as an object of type Long and not a primitive type if you want to use one of its functions.

As suggested, it is even simpler to just use a double variable instead of a long from the start:

```
double amount = 123456;
int decimal = 2;
amount = amount / Math.pow(10, decimal);
```

Comment: What is `l` in your code? It is not declared or set anywhere.

Comment: @StephenP You are right, it was a typo, I wrote `l` by mistake because I was thinking that it is a long variable. Thank you!!

Comment: Ok, you replaced `l` — but a **primitive** `long` like amount doesn't have methods; it is a _primitive_. You can't do `longvalue.doubleValue()`, you would need to use a `Long` object, not a primitive.

Comment: *just declare one of amount/decimal as double* No need for doubleValue() or Long objects

Comment: @StephenP Correct, I edited my answer. So, yeah be careful to use an object of type Long and not a primitive type in order to use one of its functions. Certainly, there are many other similar ways to dynamically add a decimal separator point to a number, but I think this is the most simple and easier to comprehend.

Comment: You actually _can_ do it without objects, as aran says, even if you're not allowed to change the declared types of `amount` or `decimal` because the return type of `Math.pow` is `double`. If you have `long amount` and `int decimal` like in the OP question, you can do: `double newAmount = amount / java.lang.Math.pow(10, decimal);`

Comment: @aron I added your suggestion. I wanted to use the OP's example's initial variables as they are, to provide a better explanation and in case he had to use necessarilly these type of variables. But, I added your improvement, if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required number by dividing the given number by 10 ^ decimalPlaces e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNum(123456, 2));
        System.out.println(getNum(123456, 4));
    }

    static double getNum(long val, int decimalPlaces) {
        return val / Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234.56
12.3456
```

Answer (score -1):

All the other answers suggest converting to `double` and then scaling by powers of 10 before displaying. This will result in some unexpected results because of a loss of precision in the scaling operation.  For the complete, gory details on why, please read
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

As to your problem, you should be doing the work using `BigDecimal`.  Converting from `long` (or `Long`) to `BigDecimal` does not lose precision, and will always produce the expected results.

BigDecimal even has a method to do the scaling for you:

```
long amount = 123456;
int decimal = 2;
BigDecimal n = BigDecimal.valueOf(amount).scaleByPowerOfTen(-decimal);
```

Output:

```
1234.56
```